# how to get the values from the custom lightning table on the click of the user

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, datatable

i have a custom lightning datatable and if user click on the particular item of the table on the particular row then it should fetch that particular value and store in the track property of the lwc component.

currently i am using for loop to get the value kindly help me to get the alternate method as per the req.

below is my for loop:

```
handleGetvalue(event) {
        let inputvalue = '';
        let key = event.target.getAttribute('Id1');
        for (let row of this.obj) {
            if (row.uniqueId === rowKey) {
                inputvalue = row.Id; //assigning the value
                
           }
        }
    }
    
    
    HTML markup:
    <a href={uyir} Id={ASDDD} onclick={handleGetvalue} >{IDVALUE}</a>
```

kindly suggest me any alternative way for this .

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataset attributes on the onclick event tag that is inside custom lightning datatable html part and use below code in JS to get Values

HTML Part

   `<button onclick={assDesk} data-stname={rec.Student_Name__c} data-id={rec.Student_Name__c} class="actions"> </button>`

JS Part

```
let stdname = event.target.dataset.stname; this.name = stdname;
 let val =this.template.querySelector('[data-stname="' + stdname + '"]');
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Or u Can change CSS as well

 1. this.template.querySelector('[data-id="' +
    eventdel.target.dataset.studentname + '"]').disabled = false;
            
 2. this.template.querySelector('[data-label=ClassSource]').disabled =
        false;
 3. this.template.querySelector('[data-stname="' +
    eventdel.target.dataset.studentname  + '"]').style.opacity ='1'
```